# Ansible error when using in variable equal sign

Tags: ansible

I have ansible role. When start ansibple-playbook main.yml -C get this error:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found unknown escape character

The error appears to be in '/main': line 41, column 93, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

service          : "-XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx3584m -Xms3584m -Xmn896m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:SurvivorRatio=5 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=10 -XX:InitialTenuringThreshold=10 -Xloggc:gclogs/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2000k"
                                                                                            ^ here

There appears to be both 'k=v' shorthand syntax and YAML in this task. Only one syntax may be used.
This one looks easy to fix. It seems that there is a value started
with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
with the same kind of quote. For instance:

    when: "ok" in result.stdout

Could be written as:

   when: '"ok" in result.stdout'

Or equivalently:

   when: "'ok' in result.stdout"
```

in our group_vars folder we use variable like this:

```
service          : "-XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx3584m -Xms3584m -Xmn896m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:SurvivorRatio=5 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=10 -XX:
InitialTenuringThreshold=10 -Xloggc:gclogs/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:+PrintGCDate
Stamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2000k"
```

this is command to start as systemd unit.
Where i mistake ? 
I think that error in equal sign but i`m cant replace it.

Comment: Hi Sergey and welcome to SO. Your question as it is is not answerable. Please read [How to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the help section. Then edit your question and provide the necessary information for others to help you (A minimal playbook, an inventory if needed, your loaded vars, a run with -vvv option to see errors....).

Answer (score 1):

This must be some problem with the formatting or indentation. The play below works as expected.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    svc: "-XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx3584m -Xms3584m -Xmn896m -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:SurvivorRatio=5
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090
          -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
          -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=10 -XX:InitialTenuringThreshold=10 -Xloggc:gclogs/gc.log
          -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime
          -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
          -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=2000k"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: svc
```